# Combine insertion sort with quick sort function relationship

Tags: quicksort, insertion-sort, hybrid

**A hybrid sorting:**
array A's element index from int p to int r, we initially sort A[] by quick sort method, the pivot is initially placed at the end of the array, then recursively call quick sort, however as the number of elements in the array is smaller than t, then we stop call quick sort and sort the rest of element by insertion sort, the hybrid function should return the times of calling insertion sort only. The main function print out the times of calling insertion sort.

I write this code several times yet always such a mess on the relationship of functions, a huge amount of bug information that I can't diagnose. 
and I don't know why it is a faster implementation in practice than combining with randomized_quick_sort. Thanks

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
// hybrid quick sort
int hybridsort(int A[], int p, int q, int t);

int  main() {
  int n = 9, t = 3;
  int A[9] = {1, 8, 6, 3, 2, 7, 4, 9, 10};

  for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++)printf(" %d", A[i]);
  printf("\n");

  int res = hybridsort(A, 0, n - 1, t);// rest
  printf("No. of calls = %d\n",res);

  for(int i = 0; i< 9; i++)printf("%d", A[i]);
  printf("\n");

  return 0;
}
int hybridsort(int A[], int p, int r, int t){
  int n, count;
  count = 0;
  int i, j, key;
  n = p - r + 1;
  // if No.elements < t, # of insertion sort gets called
  if(n >= t && p > r ){
      quicksort(A, p, r);
    }
    else{
      // insertionsort
      count = count + 1;
      for(j = 1; j < 6; j++){
      key = A[j];
      i = j - 1;
      while(i > -1 && A[i] > key){
      A[i + 1] = A[i];
      i = i - 1;
    }
    A[i + 1] = key;
   }

 }
}

return count;
}
void quicksort(int A[], int p, int r){
  int q ;
  if(p < r){

    q = partition(A, p,r);
    quicksort(A, p, q - 1);
    quicksort(A, q + 1, r);
  }
}

int partition(int A[], int p, int r){
  int x, i, j, tmp;
  x = A[r];//pivot
  i = p - 1;
  for(j = p; j < r; j++){
    if(A[j] <= x){
      i += 1;
      tmp = A[i];
      A[i] = A[j];
      A[j] = tmp;
    }

  }
  tmp = A[i + 1];
  A[i + 1] = A[r];
  A[r] = tmp;
  return i + 1 ;// pivot index position after sorting

}
```

Comment: For a hybrid insertion + quick sort, the quick sort should be calling insertion sort for smaller sub-array sizes. In my answer, I chose to use insertion sort if the size <= 32 elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example hybrid quick + insertion sort. The main program would call QuickSort(), which will call InsertionSort for sub-array sizes <= 32.

```
void InsertionSort(int a[], size_t lo, size_t hi)
{
size_t i = lo+1;
size_t j;
int t;
    while(i <= hi){
        t = a[i];
        j = i;
        while((j > lo) && a[j-1] > t){
            a[j] = a[j-1];
            j -= 1;
        }
    a[j] = t;
    i += 1;
    }
}

void QuickSort(int a[], size_t lo, size_t hi)
{
    if(lo >= hi)
        return;
    if((hi-lo) < 32){
        InsertionSort(a, lo, hi);
        return;
    }
    int pivot = a[lo + (hi - lo) / 2];
    int t;
    size_t i = lo - 1;
    size_t j = hi + 1;
    while(1)
    {
        while (a[++i] < pivot);
        while (a[--j] > pivot);
        if (i >= j)
            break;
        t = a[i];
        a[i] = a[j];
        a[j] = t;
    }
    QuickSort(a, lo, j);
    QuickSort(a, j + 1, hi);
}
```

Comment: Although it is one of the elementary sorting algorithms with O(n2) worst-case time, insertion sort is the algorithm of choice either when the data is nearly sorted (because it is adaptive) or when the problem size is small (because it has low overhead).For these reasons, and because it is also stable, insertion sort is often used as the recursive base case (when the problem size is small) for higher overhead divide-and-conquer sorting algorithms, such as merge sort or quick sort. 
 https://www.toptal.com/developers/sorting-algorithms#    I saw this from other post

Comment: Thanks for your encouragement from the beginning, I think my code is like trash https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging and I try to use tool to debug but this time I really don't know why my code doesn't work. could you please give me a further comment on code is possible? I saw you have answered a lot about sorting some technical analysis beyond my understanding so I just focus mainly on code right now

Comment: int pivot = a[lo + (hi - lo) / 2]; Is this the same with 'int pivot = (lo + hi)/2' ? but your version allow the program to choose mid pivot on every subarray with element _num > t and avoid overflow? Is it the same with choosing a random pivot basically?

Comment: the hybrid function should return the times of calling insertion sort only. this was a hw question and they only used hybrid sort and main (only two functions)

Comment: Is it too easy that I should switch to beginner's forum^^?

Comment: `pivot = a[lo + (hi - lo) / 2] versus (lo + hi)/2` - this avoids overflow, but the chance of overflow only exists in specific cases. For a 32 bit environment with 32 bit indexes, overflow could only occur if sorting a character array of size >= 2GB, which is unlikely. In languages that don't support unsigned indexes, then the limit would be 1GB of elements, which isn't possible with elements >= 4 bytes in size, such as 32 bit integers. In most 64 bit environments, `size_t` is 64 bits, and overflow isn't possible since there isn't that much memory.

Comment: In general, when adding counters to profile existing code, it is simpler to use global counters rather than modify the interfaces to functions being used.